# restarting resolvconf service not update /etc/resolv.conf in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, resolvconf

I'm following the method 2 in https://linuxhint.com/update-resolv-conf-on-ubuntu/ to updating resolve.conf file. So when I changed file /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head, and restart service by command `systemctl restart resolvcon`

The file resolve.conf have no changes, this issue only happen with Ubuntu 22.04, as tested with Ubuntu 18.04, this method works fine.
I've to run command `resolvconf -u`, so the resolve.conf can be updated in Ubuntu 22.04

is there something wrong with resolvconf service?